# Using a different .eslintrc config file for typescript and javascript in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-eslint

I have a project with both JS and TS files (and JSX/TSX). I have a separate `.eslintrc.json` file for JS vs. TS. I'd like to be able to tell VSCode which eslint config file to use depending on the file extension.

Tried putting the settings in `settings.json` under the `[typescript]` field but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be possible to use 1 file and `overrides` option:

**`.eslintrc.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
    "root": true,
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
    "rules": {
        // JavaScript rules
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
            "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
            "parserOptions": {
                "project": "./tsconfig.json"
            },
            "plugins": [
                "@typescript-eslint"
            ],
            "rules": {
                // TypeScript rules
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And changing workspace settings:

```
"eslint.validate": [
    {
        "language": "typescript",
        "autoFix": true
    },
    {
        "language": "typescriptreact",
        "autoFix": true
    }
]
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I'm using the `extends` directive in my `.eslintrc.json` file and it doesn't look like I can put that in the overrides section (but I want different `extends` for my js vs ts files).

Comment: I thought `extends` supports `overrides` https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8813

Comment: You are right. As of version 6, I was on version 5. Thanks, accepted your answer.